# What order did the events of Episode 2 happen?

Tags: occultic-nine

In episode 2 ("My Cold Dimension") of the anime adaptation of Occultic;Nine, things clearly happened out of order and dates were flashed on the screen prior to each scene. What is the grand order of things that happened? It seemed to jump back and forth and I wasn't able to keep up...

Comment: Personally I found Episode 1 hard to keep up with. It seems like the series is really fast paced. I could barely even read all the subtitles... :-(

Comment: @KazRodgers I agree. Steins;Gate had a 12 episode ramp up to when things got crazy and Robotics;Notes was relatively slow as well. I was surprised with how quickly Occultic;Nine kicked things off.